# I want to steal a dolphin from captivity and release him in open water. What do I need to know?

Tags: mammals

I don't actually want to do this, but I'm writing a story and I'd like it to be scientifically accurate. A marine biologist will be doing the heist, so any advanced and cool knowledge is welcome.

Comment: No marine biologist would put a dolphin on the path for sure death.

Comment: Any particular place you plan on stealing it from? I'm sure an inland zoo would have more logistics than a fenced-off ocean bay.

Comment: what resources do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @RonJohn, if any economist would really trust what they say, they would not write books for a living, but rather speculate on the stock exchange. Instead a dolphin unused to chase food and escape predators is going to find a quick death.

Comment: @L.Dutch my point is that "experts" aren't always that smart or wise.

Comment: Orpheus, you need to watch *Free Willy*.

Comment: @RonJohn you do know that Keiko died a horrible death after being released into the sea, right? I can't think of an example worse than Free Willy.

Comment: You are basically asking if someone would tell you in an answer that's maybe 1000 words if it's really long what you learn in years of studying and working close with animals. Please realize that this is impossible. Write about stuff you know. This is similar to asking: i want a character to speak Russian. How do I do that? Well, learn Russian for a couple of years. But at the very least you should demonstrate that you did some research

Comment: @Raditz_35 So, you're saying I should study Rocket Science to send a ship to outer space? Asking people is another kind of research.

Comment: Hellow Orpheus.  Your question has been flagged for a number of issues.  Let me help.  (a) Real-world questions are welcome here, but they're expected to be in the context of developing a fictional world - not a specific story.  Storybuilding is not what we do.  (b) At all SE sites you are expected to have done research and are asking us about aspects of that research you don't understand (this is, after all, a Q&A site, not a discussion forum).  Your question is expected to reflect this, but does not.  (c) The only way to answer any question is to have enough detail.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  You've provided no detail at all.  Where is the dolphin?  What are the circumstances of the theft?  What condition is the dolphin in?  What kind of dolphin is it?  What's the weather like during the heist?  Are we in a city?  Rural?  A deserted island?  Is it present day?  100 years ago?  100 years from now?  What resources are available to the biologist?  Does he have a team?  Does he know how to pick locks?  This is what we mean - you haven't done your research and we won't write your story for you.

Comment: @Renan why do you all think that I'm advocating this, or think it's a good idea?

Comment: @Orpheus1844 not only should you but you have to in order to be scientifically accurate. Any project with money has an expert on board so it makes sense.
 You absolutely don't have to if you want to spend little time on boring details. For example, the question: "has it ever or can it be done?" Is a perfect fit. But currently this is asking for  things you don't learn in a se answer. The scope of the question shows that the op is completely unfamiliar with their idea, thus my advice: if you don't even know enough to know where to start, you probably shouldn't write a book about it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You Will Probably Kill It**

The task of moving a dolphin safeley requires a dedicated team of highly trained and educated specialists working 24/7 with extremeley expensive specialized equipment. If your amatuer attempt doesnt outright kill it then it will die in the ocean since modern day dolphins in captivity were not captured from the wild, but bred, born, and raised in captivity. They not only have never had to survive outside of a perfectly controlled environment with regular feedings, thier parents, grandparents, and great grandparents didnt either. Dolphins are social animals that must be taught survival behaviors from fellow pod members. They have not developed functional survival skills. In addition, one of the worst traits for survival in the wild has been trained into them. They haven't learned to steer clear of predators, or even what predators are.

Removing them from captivity will kill them. Either swiftly during the botched moving attempt, slowly starving to death in the ocean, or violently at the hands of predators.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll have my biologist do something else!

Comment: Just curious. Has anyone actually tried it? Dolphins are extremely intelligent animals, and I'd be surprised if this didn't allow them at least a chance of surviving against the odds. Humans have often survived unaded in environments and situations which logically should have killed them. Dolphins may be capable of doing the same.

Comment: The ability to identify a predator is likely to be instinctive to some extent.

Comment: The ability to identify a predator also doesn't count for much when it's a lone social animal that typically relies on a group response to predators to survive.

Comment: @user1751825 Most of dolphins brain mass is dedicated to keeping the rest of the brain warm. The idea of dolphin exceptionalism is slowly eroding as more rigor is applied to repeating and interpreting the old experiments. For example, jumping spiders are able to replicate dolphins ability to react to television screens. Sadly, so far, cetaceans raised in captivity and released into the wild have not been successfully weaned of their dependency on humans.

Comment: In most cases animals that were raised in captivity don't really do very well once reintroduced. Success stories are so sensational because they are so rare. I once spoke to an old guy who was in Africa in the 50's, he saw a lion in a cage. He felt really bad and bought it for a rather large fee and released in in the wild. He spent the next 3 weeks following it watching it slowly starve to death. He couldn't bear to put it back in a cage but it wasn't going to survive on it's own so he had to shoot it. His advice was to never put animals in a cage in the first place.

Comment: @pojo-guy I don't doubt life would be difficult, and potentially shorter for a lone dolphin. The story perhaps could be adapted to have a group of dolphins released, instead of a lone individual, and perhaps there could be some other imperative for doing so, like they're going to be euthanized otherwise. Presumably a familiar group could form their own pod, and increase their odds of survival. I think that spiders and insects may be more intelligent than most people give them credit for. I keep stick insects and I've observed behaviour which suggests to me that they can learn.

Comment: @TCAT117 The usual prey of lions tends to be notoriously difficult to catch. I understand that lions can be re-introduced to the wild, if it is done progressively, and they're allowed time to (re)learn how to hunt. Certainly they couldn't simply be all of a sudden left to fend for themselves and expected to survive.

Comment: They didn't really know that in the 50's. It was kind of just assumed that all animals operated on instinct and didn't need to be taught to perform natural tasks. If an animal couldn't the concept of the era was that they were irreparably broken.

Comment: @user1751825 my son kept jumping spiders for a while. Unlike most spiders, they are intelligent enough to have distinct personalities, and some even appear to enjoy playing with humans, I get your point about insect intelligence. Sadly, dolphins, even released as groups into curated coves, never seem to lose their dependency on humans.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Empty the tanks]

Let’s just say your plan is to go to Sea World, open a gate and let the dolphin swim to freedom. It’s an admirable plan and if you ended the story right here it would have a happy ending.

In reality, it’s going to die.

Whether it was born in captivity or captured in Taiji, Japan, you will need to train the dolphin to survive. Captive dolphins never learned how to hunt. In the open ocean, they work as a team with their pod to capture fish. When captured, the trainers in Taiji break dolphins of their independence to only take food from trainers.

You can’t have the dolphin wander into the nearest pod and have the pod adopt it like a long lost brother. They don’t adopt orphans and would likely kill your freed dolphin. So you’d have to track down its home pod and return it to its family. But nobody tracks which pod a dolphin came when it was captured, so it’s incredibly hard to integrate one back to where it belongs. Even if you knew the geographic location of the pod, they can be hard to locate even if you were only a mile away.

If you could train it to fish, the question becomes does it still have teeth to capture fish? Dolphins and whales chew on the sides of the captivity tanks and wear them down. This is an ongoing problem with captive cetaceans.

When people talk about freeing whales and dolphins, so many of us want to see it happen, but realistically best hope is to move them to a cove where full time assistants will feed and care for them, but finally they would be out of the tanks. Hopefully once dolphins are freed, they surprise us and are able to care for themselves, but that's most likely fantasy. Your heart is in the right place for this story, but sometimes reality does not offer a sparkling future.

Good luck in emptying the tanks.

Comment: *"They don’t adopt strays and would likely kill it."* Dolphins, the bottlenose specially, are known for their vicioud gang rapes. The lonely, rescued dolphin would probably suffer a fate that would traumatize his rescuer forever. Only after that thebpod would kill him.